# How should I use automatic type conversion in the sum of two complex numbers? (C++)

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I've created a class Complex for a complex number and the get/set methods to extract and change the real and imaginary part of the number. Now I want to sum and multiplicate two complex numbers, so I've created the following functions:

```
Complex somma(Complex a, Complex b) {
    Complex c;
    c.set_Rez(a.get_Rez()+b.get_Rez());
    c.set_Imz(a.get_Imz()+b.get_Imz());
    return c;
}

Complex prodotto(Complex a, Complex b) {
    Complex c;
    c.set_ro(a.get_ro()*b.get_ro());
    c.set_fi(a.get_fi()+b.get_fi());
    return c;
}
```

My question is if there is a way to have as an output of the functions a simple double if the inputs are doubles. Is it possible to give to the functions doubles and getting a double as a result?

Comment: Do you mean having a dynamic return type?

Comment: you can probably produce an overload `double somma(double a, double b) `....

Comment: Are the getters and setters really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if there is a way to have as an output of the functions a simple double if the inputs are doubles. Is it possible to give to the functions doubles and getting a double as a result?

It sounds like you want the following overloads:

```
Complex somma(Complex a, Complex b);
Complex somma(Complex a, double b);
Complex somma(double a, Complex b);
double somma(double a, double b);
```

If there is converting constructor from a `double` to a `Complex`, you can simply use:

```
Complex somma(Complex a, Complex b);
double somma(double a, double b);
```

to get what you need. You need similar functions for `prodotto`

```
Complex prodotto(Complex a, Complex b);
double prodotto(double a, double b);
```

---

Overloading the functions `somma` and `prodotto` for `Complex` and `double` makes your code look more uniform. However, it will more idiomatic to overload `operator+` and `operator*` for `Complex`.

```
Complex operator+(Complex const& lhs, Complex const& rhs) { ... }
Complex operator*(Complex const& lhs, Complex const& rhs) { ... }
```

Then you can use

```
Complex c1 = { ... };
Complex c2 = { ... };
Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
Complex c4 = c1 * c2;
```

Then, you don't have to worry about overloading `somma` and `prodotto` for `double`. You can just use `+` and `*` for objects of type `Complex` as well as type `double`.

Comment: @R Sahu thank you for your answer! May I ask you what do you mean by "converting constructor"?

Comment: @Gitana: A "converting constructor" is one that accepts a different type as input.  `Complex(double)` would be a converting constructor.  Then you can pass `double` values wherever a `Complex` value is expected

Comment: @RSahu: It would also be worth making the input parameter of the `Complex` versions be `const Complex &` instead of just `Complex`. But personally, I wouldn't use functions for this at all, I would override `operator+` and `operator*` for `Complex` instead. The compiler already knows how to add and multiple `double` values, so teach it how to add and multiple `Complex` values, too.